# ImageOverlay bounds in Leaflet from GDAL processed image

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, leaflet

I am displaying an image to Leaflet. The image is a result of a process from a backend I am also building. I cannot get the right bounds for the image. I return the bounds from the function `gdal.Info`.

```
from osgeo import gdal
src_ds = gdal.Open('./data/example_image.png')
info = gdal.Info(src_ds)
```

The image has a EPSG:4326 projection and I understand that Leaflet default is EPSG:3857. My question would be, should I reproject my Leaflet app to EPSG:4326? or am I receiving the wrong bounds from GDAL?

If I need to reproject my leaflet app to EPSG:4326, how is it done in `react-leaflet`?

Comment: All layers on Leaflet map must be in the same CRS , so if you want to use EPSG:4326, all layers must be in this CRS. To use it, just specify map option `crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326`.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, where do you import that? Should it be a parameter in the MapContainer component in react-leaflet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, so can't help you here.